Conditional redirection in wix using velo
I have a wix Plans & Pricing widget (IFrame) through which users can subscribe to a plan (Duration: 1 month) on my website. Whenever a new user signs up, he / she should be directed to a page with this widget.
However, when a returning user comes to the site, he / she should be redirected to another page. This is not based on the login only, but at a click of a button placed on a page.
Right now, all the users are reaching the Subscription page, irrespective of the subscription status.
I have tried out multiple velo codes to collect the details of the user on login.
The details are required from 2 different sources:

email from the login
subscription details stored in the wix default Data

I want to store these details in a place which are accessible, till the user logs out.
When the user reaches the page of the button, this data can be called and based on the status of the subscription, the user can be redirected.
